# GCM certificate configuration not working or iOS

Tags: ios, certificate, google-cloud-messaging, push, production

I am facing one issue when I am trying to confiure the GCM and getting configuration file. When I am trying to upload the production certificate over the GCM portal it says "**Bundle Id in certificate doesn't match with Bundle Id you entered**". I verified already for the same. Still no joy. Anyone help plz.

Comment: same issue. I have checked all bundles and all certificates, have generated new certificates, but no success

Comment: Same here .. New certiicates also not working.

Comment: I tried with 3 certificates none of them work. Also I tried all the solutions mentioned below even exporting 2 files from keychain and that too didn't work. Wondering if this is really a bug from Google as I checked every minute details but didn't found any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it with both Development and Production .p12, both worked for me.

You need to make sure you generate a correct `.cer` certificate file from your Bundle ID, and need to make sure you export the correct `.p12` file from your Keychain Access. You can view the sample steps in [this page](http://faq.appaloosa-store.com/knowledgebase/articles/61785-how-to-generate-push-notification-p12-file).

You need to make sure the `iOS Bundle ID` you input in the [GCM portal](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=gcm&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fios%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Try%20Cloud%20Messaging).
(I use mine `com.ziyang.samples.quickstart.gcm`)

[image]

matches the Bundle ID in your [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action).
(I use mine `com.ziyang.samples.quickstart.gcm`)

[image]

If I miss typed the `iOS Bundle ID` in the GCM portal, it will show the below error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for our Help. It has now resoved. :)

Comment: @Akanksha, please accept this answer, if it resolved your issue, so that other users with same issue can resolve their problems.

Comment: Try to create p12 from certificate directly (not by right clicking on the key, but on certificate).

Answer (score 34):

For my case, I have to export a cer not a private key.[image]

Comment: Saved my Day. Maybe time they fixed this in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: This should probably be added to the answer -  as it turns out, for Production you export the whole cert, for development it's just the key. Both as p12 formats though.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem but for different reason. It turns out that the `.p12` file has something wrong. If I export `.p12` file from Keychain Access by selecting both certificate and key and export 2 items together, it doesn't work. I need to export the certificate and key separately and merge them later. Use terminal to merge two files:

```
cat cert.p12 key.p12 > cert_merged.p12
```

Comment: I tried using this command but didn't help. Can you please elaborate exactly how it will behave when I have password protected p12 files?

Comment: One more question: How do you export certificate and keys separately? What I did is selected single file and exported but merging two files didn't work for me.

Comment: I selected single file and exported it, however, I left the password field blank. So those `.p12` files were not password protected. Maybe that is why I could merge them.

Comment: @Denn Currently, FCM is misleading the process. It asks to export only private key in the documentation. But, when I do that, it says bundle id not matched. When I export the whole certificate including private key, it worked. Anyway, idea of exporting both .cer & private key is from you. Credits to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I have been getting same exact problem in Firebase (FCM).

The only solution which has worked for me, which I found by hit and trial is while exporting the Cert as the P12, only select the Cert but don't select the Key.

You will still be able to export only the Cert (without the key) as a P12 file and set the password in a similar way.

Now uploading this P12 file with the provided password works for me.

**Make sure to export only the certificate not the key... by clicking on the triangular/caret dropdown icon and deselecting the key**

[image: Export only the certificate not the key... by clicking on the triangular/caret dropdown icon and deselecting the key]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using your APNS certificate and not your regular development or production certificate. Just spent an hour on this until I realised my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

if you sure you set the right bundle id You can solve it by:-

1-Export only private key as p12.

2-Export only CERT as p12.

3-Export CERT with private key as p12.

and try one by one to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please select the Certificate instead of the key in the Keychain Access while exporting it to .p12.

Answer (score 0):

**A Password is Required** when exporting the development certificate. The **Development** certificate would not upload with any of these suggestions until I added a password. I was, however, able to upload the **Release** certificate without a password. I also used the suggestion of @Sur Max to **only export the certificate** and not the key.