# Firebase: Changing APN Certificate

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, apn

I am trying to change the APNs Certificate but "The Bundle ID in the certificate does not match the Bundle ID you entered" msg appear.

Comment: Does the certificate match the bundle ID of the app you are trying to add the certificate to?

Comment: issue resolved from this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982238/gcm-certificate-configuration-not-working-or-ios