# Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null) , <FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Encounter network error. Code, error: -999

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xcode7.3

I am not able to get `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()`. Sometimes tokens are available and sometimes they are not.

I am getting this error:

> Encounter network error. Code, error: -999, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:50614245612:ios:fab42aa0b6b4439e?app_instance_id=&platform=ios&gmp_version=3402, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:50614245612:ios:fab42aa0b6b4439e?app_instance_id=&platform=ios&gmp_version=3402, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}

What is the problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firebase, they have fixed the network error issue in their previous version.

Comment: Can you share me latest link ? - Bharat Modi

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: Sorry , already use latest firebase version , still not working properly , sometime token provided otherwise show above error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found solution :- 
APNS certificate not properly create p12 file. Download file from apple developer account and create p12 file by concatenate command in terminal, follow below steps :-

1) create p12 of APNS certificate 
2) create p12 of private key 
3) open terminal and write concatenate command 
4) cat apnsDev.p12 privateKey.p12 > certMerge.p12

This work for me

Reference from this link of stackoverflow :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470374/5242836