# Google cloud messaging with iOS error bundle id

Tags: ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

[I'm have an issue when I create google cloud messaging with iOS platform. 
"The Bundle ID in the certificate does not match the Bundle ID you entered." I typed with right bundle id but GCM show this error.
]
[Click here to show the image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH69x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this issue comes when exporting the certificate. So to resolve this problem, I found in this [Github issue](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/111) that you need to export the certificate as the P12 and only select the certificate without the Key then set the password in a similar way.

For another solution to this problem, check this related SO question: [GCM certificate configuration not working or iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982238/gcm-certificate-configuration-not-working-or-ios)

Hope it helps you.